# Geometry Nodes: How to copy the normals of a mesh and use it on curves?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a toon shading for Geometry Hair nodes and I wanted to use the normals of the character for the curves instead of using the normals of the curves.

How can I tell it to do that with geometry nodes?

Answer (score 2):

GN doesn't yet support custom normals, but for most purposes, use of normal-like attributes is sufficient:

[image]

In the GN, I'm realizing instances (since your objects are likely instances, and we need to put individual data on each of those instances), then just sampling the normal of the nearest surface of an object-- here, a plane.

I output that nearest surface normal to a point vector attribute, and in the modifier, assign that to something ("custNorm".)

In the shader nodes, I'm reading my GN attribute, normalizing it (although the point data is normalized, the interpolation of that point data across a surface is not necessarily normalized), and then using it wherever I have any inputs asking for a normal.

There are situations where this doesn't work (refraction doesn't play nicely with arbitrary normals), and Blender doesn't shade things very well when the shader normal deviates strongly from the true face normal (not sure exactly when that started happening, it used to do just fine) so there are things to be concerned about, but this is how you do it.